# How to install scipy with pip3?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pip

I got the following error when I try to install `scipy` with `pip3` on Mac OS X 10.14.1. Does anybody know what the problem is? I was able to install scipy with pip2.

```
$ pip3 install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/5b/5afcd1c46f97b3c2ac3489dbc95d6ca28eacf8e3634e51f495da68d97f0f/scipy-1.3.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/mktemp/tmp9rjyv64p
         cwd: /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-install-w63x23dy/scipy
    Complete output (50 lines):
    setup.py:386: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-install-w63x23dy/scipy/pip-wheel-metadata'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        from . import multiarray
    ImportError: dlopen(/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-38m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _aheapsort_bool
      Referenced from: /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-38m-darwin.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-38m-darwin.so

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 197, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 69, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 236, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 505, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 481, in setup_package
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
        from . import add_newdocs
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .type_check import *
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
        import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
      File "/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError:
    Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
    likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
    If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
    files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

    Original error was: dlopen(/private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-38m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _aheapsort_bool
      Referenced from: /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-38m-darwin.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-4kdqsfzb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-38m-darwin.so

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/mktemp/tmp9rjyv64p Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.2, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: How about reinstall `numpy` and then install `scipy`?

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: was the error still the same? Or you can try to install with `conda`?

Comment: The error stays the same. I don't use conda, because conda may cause conflict in other cases.

Comment: How about creating a new environment? I think there are conflictions in this base environment.

Comment: This is a basic package that I want to use. I don't want to go into an environment every time when I want to use the package. Is there a way to resolve the problem in the base environment?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? having the exact same problem (works with pip, but not pip3)